# "Refused to execute script because its MIME type..." for a website hosted on Amazon server

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, gulp, babeljs, mime-types

It's quite hard to explain the problem I'm facing but I will try.

As the title suggests, I'm getting a wrong MIME type error on some javascript files that my website sources from. I didn't have this problem before. Funny thing is, it goes away and comes back on its own. I heard that it has something to do with Chrome's recent change due to security.

The error says my script type is `binary/octet-stream` when it should be `application/script`. So I added the `type="application/script"` to all the script references but the error still remains.

As far as the project environment goes, I use `Babel` to manage my website along with `Gulp` to run tasks and I use `Amazon server` to host the site and push it through `Github`.

I wonder if there is a way I can explicitly configure `MIME type` in a `Babel` project or configure something on `Amazon server` side to adapt to the recent Chrome change.

I don't know if this is enough detail to go about this problem so please let me know if you need more info. I've been googling for a while but haven't quite encountered a case with my exact settings.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the `type` attribute of your script.

`Content-Type` is a header sent from the server to the client when you request a file. It tells the client what kind of file it has requested.

A few months ago, browsers would simply assume any url in a script's `src` was a Javascript file. It recently became a requirement that that those files have a Javascript content type. (The content type has nothing to do with the file extention).

Github is not a CDN, you should not be linking to Javascript files from Github in your pages. In order to prevent people abusing their servers, Github (and others) now serve their raw Javascript files with a plaintext content type (except on github.io).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm not linking my javascript files from Github. I use libraries like https://cdnjs.com/libraries/gsap and other scripts are compiled from Gulp and lives in a hosted server. My point is I haven't mentioned Github as a CDN..Or is there something I'm not quite understanding here?

Comment: Please elaborate on "you should not be linking to Javascript files from Github in your pages" as I genuinely feel not getting the idea and also if you could point out in more detail what I can do to address this..Thanks, really appreciate this.

Comment: @SeongLee - You said you "push your files thru Github" - if your site is being constructed via your Github repository there is a chance Github is serving them as plaintext. I was mainly just explaining the root cause of the problem. I (nor anyone else) can tell you how to fix it unless you provide more information. If you shared a link to the site that is causing the problem that would be a start.

Comment: By “push thru github” I meant pushing a code commit to a private github where version is maintained. The site lives in Amazon server and is not a github hosted page. The error is now gone so it won’t show that error but i need to prevent it from happening next time. As your answer suggests I’d likento know how I can explicitly tell what ‘Content-type’ it is to the client.

Comment: @SeongLee - You can see any request's content type by looking in the "Network" tab of the developer console of your browser. There is usually a "headers" section which shows all the request's headers, including Content-Type. Uless you're going to share some new details there's nothing further I can do to help you. Good luck.